# Getting Select Option Value from Controller : ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is the code in View Section:

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    @foreach (var country in countries)
    {
        <option value="@country.CountryId"> @country.CountryName</option>
    }
 </select>
```

Code to get value from Controller:

```
public ActionResult IndexPost()
{
    ViewBag.Countries = CountryRepository.GetCountries();

    if (Request["btnSubmitCountry"] != null)
    {
        string country = Request["country"];
        ViewBag.Msg = "You have selected " + country;
    }
    return View();
```

I wanted to Request to get value the name of the Country too, but right now it only gets the id. Can you please help me to get the id and name both using this only this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because select returns the value of the value,But you can use the hidden tag to store the text value.

**E.g:**

```html
  <form onsubmit="var sel=document.getElementById('country');document.getElementById('country_text').value=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;">
    <select name="country" id="country">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            @foreach (var country in countries)
            {
                <option value="@country.CountryId"> @country.CountryName</option>
            }
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="country_text" id="country_text" />
  </form>
```

**get text:**

```cs
string countryText = Request["country_text"];
```

Comment: It works using JS, is there any way we can grab that text value from the select option without using JS? Also, thank you for the above solution.